# Probabilistic interpretation of Malus's law

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, photons

A beam of photons is polarized in the vertical direction. What is the probability that a photon will pass two filters, the first at $45^{\circ}$ and the other at $75^{\circ}$?

The answer is given by $\cos^{2}(45) \cdot \cos^{2}(30) = 0.375$, but I do not understand why the answer is not $\cos^{2}(45) \cdot \cos^{2}(75).$ Where is the $30^{\circ}$ coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plane of polarisation of the second filter is orientated at $75^\circ -45^\circ = 30^\circ$ relative to the first filter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When the photons come out of the first filter, they have been repolarized to match the orientation of that filter. It's probably easier to understand this in terms of EM waves; the filter just blocks the component of the wave that is polarized perpendicular to itself.

Then, when the photons/EM waves encounter the second filter, the attentuation factor depends on the angle between the filter ($75^\circ$ from their initial polarization) and their polarization *at that moment* ($45^\circ$ from their initial polarization).